# Why my react native app crashes on Android after 5-10 minutes in background state?

Tags: android, react-native

On android my react native app crashes when it remains 5-10 minutes in background and after that i open it again.
Can anyone please tell me why it's crashing?

Comment: You need to post the stacktrace and any code that might be relevant in respect to the stacktrace, this typically happens when  the app can't be restored properly. Like for instance if you were using Fragments and passed arguments through a constructor instead of a bundle. When the app starts back up it recreates the fragment from its default constructor which doesn't have arguments and the second you use one of those args it will be null, because they were never passed.